# how to get arc diff on the command line to assume yes on very large number of changes

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

My Jenkins server is running arc diff, and once in a while I have large diffs, I don't want my job to fail if that is the case:

Right with the latest master of arc, I get:

```
This diff has a very large number of changes (762). Differential works
best for changes which will receive detailed human review, and not as
well for large automated changes or bulk checkins. See
https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/differential_large_changes/
for information about reviewing big checkins. Continue anyway? [y/N] 
[1mUsage Exception:[m Aborted generation of gigantic diff.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

My current code tries to avoid interactivity and mostly works, except for large diffs. Any way around this?

```
echo "jenkins

Summary:

Test Plan:
required
Reviewers:
alberto56
Subscribers:

JIRA Issues:
$JIRAISSUE" > arc_info.txt

arc diff --allow-untracked --message jenkins --message-file arc_info.txt origin/master

rm arc_info.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `no interaction` option (yet) for `arc diff`. You may wanna try something like:

```
echo 'y' | arc diff ...
```

or even

```
echo 'y y y' | arc diff ...
```

You could also use the **Yes** command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes